# Salesforce Marketing cloud - block incoming SMS replies for a short code that do not map to a keyword

Tags: sms, salesforce-marketing-cloud

We have a SMS campaign set up. We have configured the keywords associated to the short code.

I understand that if a user reply using a keyword that is not associated to the short code (sometimes that's literal gibberish) that reply is registered in marketing cloud (obviously no subsequent action occurs). Is it possible to block any of these messages that are not mapped keywords associated with the short code?

Regards
Sid